# How to add string to empty lines of file in scripting?

Tags: bash, unix, sh, aix

Example : file1 has data like

```
abc 
cab

def
xxy
zay

sri

ram
```

In this file 3rd,7th,9th lines are empty, how to fill this empty lines with Specific string?.

For example if i want to fill these lines with `Hello`

Output File should be like:

```
abc 
cab
Hello
def
xxy
zay
Hello
sri
Hello
ram
```

Comment: search for regex `^$` and replace with your string

Comment: You can use `sed` or `awk`

Comment: Thnq, im new to this shell programming started learning now.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/^$/Hello/' file1` 
will output what you want.

You can redirect that to the output file as below.

`sed 's/^$/Hello/' file1 > file2`

If you want to change the original file itself, you can use the `-i` option.

`sed -i 's/^$/Hello/' file1`

Comment: i'm confused to use this 'sed' , where can get good stuff about this from basics

Comment: See [**Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial**](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) just take your time, `sed` is a big animal, you have to eat it one bite at a time...